# How to do synchronous initial fill up for ReplicatedMap in Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

As mentioned in the [Hazelcast documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/technicaldesign.html):

> If a new member joins, there are two ways of handling the initial 
>   provisioning that is executed to replicate all existing values to the new 
>   member.
>
> First, you can have an async fill up which does not block reads while the 
>   fill up operation is underway…
>
> ⋮
>
> Or second, you can preform a synchronous initial fill up which blocks 
>   every read or write access to the map until the fill up operation is 
>   finished. …

How can I configure it for synchronous initial fill up?

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide a link to the documentation you quote, as it might help future users.

Comment: Added the documentation link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure why there is no configuration example in the docs about it but it is explained in the XSD:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-config-3.4.xsd#L528

Just configure the boolean value with key "async-fillup" in your replicatedmap config (in XML or via ReplicatedMapConfig in code) to false.